# Count possible grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, grouping

I dont know how to count the possible groups in a column in pandas in a efficient way.
I want to classify into groups the products that are most repeated in customer purchases.
For example:

| Client | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B |
| 2 | B,C,D |
| 3 | A,B,C |
| 4 | C,D,E |
| 5 | A,B,C,D |

```
Groups = {A,B}, {C,D}, {A,B,C}, {B,C}, {B,C,D}
Count of Group {A,B} = 3 (Client 1-3-5)
Count of Group {C,D} = 3 (Client 2-4)
Count of Group {A,B,C} = 2 (Client 3-5)
Count of Group {B,C} = 3 (Client 2-3-5)
Count of Group {B,C,D} = 2 (Client 2,5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `get_dummies` to separate the `Products`, then loop through the groups and count:

```
Groups = [{'A','B'}, {'C','D'}, {'A','B','C'}, {'B','C'}, {'B','C','D'}]
s = df.Product.str.get_dummies(',')
out = pd.Series([s[list(group)].all(1).sum() for group in Groups], 
                index=list(map(tuple, Groups)))
```

Output:

```
(A, B)       3
(C, D)       3
(C, A, B)    2
(C, B)       3
(C, D, B)    2
dtype: int64
```